# Is the onwheel event triggered by a trackpad scroll

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, mouseevent, trackpad

Although it's a basic question, I haven't been able to find an answer. However, since it's such a basic question, not much of an explanation can be provided. Unfortunately, I do not have a laptop that I can use to test this.

```
ele.onwheel = function(e) {

}
```

Is the `onwheel` event triggered by "scrolling" a laptop's trackpad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Even `deltaY` is available, but it's value depends on current trackpad or mouse.

Comment: How do the values differ? For example, how is the `e.deltaY` value different from mouse to trackpad?

Comment: I don't now definitely. But I test some mouses, once it was 100 per one wheel, and another time it was 120 per one wheel. So it's impossible to get 50 for example. But with trackpad I can get even fraction.

Comment: ohhh ok i think those values merely reflect the "scroll" amount, whereas the "scroll" direction is usually indicated by that value being negative or positive. im pretty sure these amounts can be changed in the browser itself

Comment: was that also the case for the trackpad? was "scrolling/mouse wheel down" a negative value and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, negative values are supported. It works just like mouse event "onwheel". The difference only in minimal increment or decrement. I repeat, when I use one mouse increment was 100, with another mouse it was 120. With my trackpad it was less than 1. Maybe with another trackpads it will be exectly 1, or 5 for example. You can confidently now just sign of deltaY. So I reommend you to normalize this value. After every "onweel" event check was it "positive" or "negative" scroll and so increment or decrement some constant to some variable, which saves your scroll progress.

Comment: ok thanks. thats all i needed to know. as long as "down scroll" is positive and "up scroll" is negative, then i should be fine